# PouchDB with Laravel (without CouchDB)

Tags: laravel, pouchdb

How can I use PouchDB as my LocalStorage to Sync with my Laravel API Server without using CouchDB? Some recommendation?

Comment: Since PouchDB [API requests](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_over_http) must be [CouchDB compliant](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/basics.html) the only way I can think of to make this work, is to write your own implementation within Laravel that understand the requests, processes them and sends back appropriate responses, in short write your own implementation of CouchDB's API but with your own storage (since I guess that's the actual reason behind this).

Comment: @Bogdan `but with your own storage` What kind of storage are you referring to?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I was referring to any storage engine really (although document based ones would be better since they would make abstraction easier). But before looking for solutions that allow the use of PouchDB with anything other than CouchDB (which it was specifically designed for) I would really look into alternative approaches, because this is like trying to stuff a tire into a pillow cover, you might get it in but it won't feel or look nice :).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I dont think you can use PouchDB in that way. It was desinged to use as local-storage for offline access(data only releated to each user). So, It must sync back to server or appropriate database like couchDB.

Answer (score 1):

As of June 2019, PouchDB can sync with MySQL, but it takes some extra work.

As per the [PouchDB FAQ](https://pouchdb.com/faq.html):

> PouchDB Server – An HTTP API written on top of PouchDB. Additionally, it
>   supports alternate backends like in-memory, Redis, Riak and **MySQL** [emphasis added] via
>   [the LevelUP ecosystem](https://github.com/Level/levelup/wiki/Modules#storage). Note that your application must use the PouchDB
>   API rather than directly modifying the database, however.